# SQL Server returns Date and Time instead of just Date. ASP.net Webpages

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-webpages

I'm making a website using ASP.net Webpage's in WebMatrix 3. 
I have a database (SQL Server) with a table that contains a record of events. A InDate Column, type [Date](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb630352.aspx), is the primary key. However inputted data is rendered as "4/5/2014 12:00:00 AM".

Is this normal? And if it is, how do you remove the time from the date?
I have tried looking up a lot of different resources. But found nothing that helped my situation.

If there is any pointers,tips,suggestions or if you need more info. Please let me know.

Thanks'

**Update**
Here is the cshtml file as requested.

```
@{
   Layout = "~/Layouts/_Site.cshtml";
   PageData.Add("Title","Overview");
   var talkDB = Database.Open("Events");
   string incomingQuery = string.Format("SELECT InDate,Event FROM IncomingEvents WHERE InDate >= GETDATE() AND InDate <= DATEADD(week, 5, GETDATE())");

}


<div id="upcomingEvents" class="alertBox">
    <div id="IncomingEvents">
        <h3>Incoming Events</h3>
        <table class="alertBox">
            @foreach(var row in talkDB.Query(incomingQuery))
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        @row.InDate
                    </td>
                    <td>@row.Event</td>
                    <td>edit</td>
                </tr>
            }
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please provide an example of the cshtml you are using to display the date value.

Comment: A .net date always includes a time component.  `Date.ToString` will always display this time component.  You need to format the date to remove the time, for example: `Date.ToShortDateString`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason it is displayed with a time in your web page is because there is no Date type in .NET - only DateTime and other similar types.  When you get a Date type from SQL Server, .NET casts it implicitly as a DateTime.  Since there is no time specified in the Date that came from SQL Server, the 0-value is used, which is 12:00:00AM.

In order to display just the date on your web page, you need to write your front-end code to do so.

This can be done by a call to .ToString() on the date property of your data model objects, with the appropriate format string passed in.

See this link for all of the arguments to DateTime.ToString() and what they do:
[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

You most likely want something like this:

```
@row.InDate.ToString("M/d/yyyy");
```

Which has a short-hand function:

```
@row.InDate.ToShortDateString();
```

Comment: No problem. I highly suggest bookmarking that page I provided, because you'll need it again in the future, guaranteed.  I find myself referencing it from time to time, when I need to show a date/time in a different way.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I have a feeling I will be needing it again soon enough.